# I'm Trying to make a selfbot that will send embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

i dont know how to put image url and stuff and make it appear can y'all help me please

```
@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx, colour, title, description, *,url):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed=discord.Embed(colour=colour, title=title, type='rich', description=description, url=url, timestamp=None)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Self-bots have been clearly marked as not-allowed by Discord. Any attempt at making such a program could lead to your account being banned by Discord. You’re still able to make a regular bot account (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Discord.py no longer supports self bots -> `message.content` will always be `None`

Comment: @FluxedScript, that has nothing to do with what OP asked

Comment: I tried that but it wont show image
```@bot.command()
async def e(ctx, colour, title, description, *,url):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed=discord.Embed(colour=colour, title=title, 
    description=description, url=url)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i2.wp.com/digiseller.ru/preview/879079/p1_2964281_c6b2cafd.gif")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of selfbots being forbidden by the Discord ToS,
you can look up all possible attributes in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#embed)

For example, you can set images via

```
embed.set_image(url)
```

Or thumbnail via

```
embed.set_thumbnail(url)
```